# How to call a function by setting a time period

Tags: reactjs

I want to achieve a process where by I update my firestore database after every new month.

So I am having this function below

```
export const updateSubPlan = (uid) => async (dispatch) => {
  const subplan = 2
  var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
   userRef.update({
      plan: subplan,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Sub plan updated');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('Error updating subplan:', errorMessage);
  });
}
```

I want the `updateSubPlan` function to be automatically triggered once after every new month.

So let's say it is triggered today which is `1/10/2022`, the next time it will be triggered will be `1/11/2022`.

how can I achieve this functionality in react.js

Comment: Are you wanting this to run only when the user is on the site? Keep in mind React is client side code, which means that it runs on the user's machine, and only when they're actively on the page. It can't do any background logic or execute code when no-one is on the site.

Comment: You could make it so you keep track if the user has updated, and have the user send the update the first time they visit in a new month, but users who never visit will never update. This sounds like code that should be run in a scheduled firebase cloud function (which runs on the backend)

Comment: @Nathan Thank you for your response, just as you said, I think scheduling a firebase cloud function is something similar to what I want because, I want the function to be triggered even if the users are not active. So how could I possibly achieve that, any tutorial or reference?

Comment: Start with [the main documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), to understand what cloud functions are and how to use them. Then, follow [this guide on scheduling cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). Cloud functions are awesome, have fun!

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for your help, I will follow the guide

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way!

Just call your function if `isFirstDayOfMonth` is `true`

```js
let isFirstDayOfMonth =  new Date().toISOString().slice(8, 10) === "01";

isFirstDayOfMonth 
     ? console.log( "Yes, Today is first day of month" )
     : console.log("No, Today date is " + isFirstDayOfMonth )
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use his external library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-cron